# Getting specific network information in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, networking

I'm not sure if this is a fault by me, or if my PowerShell isn't operating correctly.

```
get-netipconfiguration | where {$_.subnetmask}
```

I'm not really able to find any examples online that work either. I even tried using a `WMI` command and it still won't work. I have the latest version of PowerShell and have done this before, but my previous method is not working. Currently I'm using this for `IPaddress` fetching which works wonderfully

```
$ipaddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address.IPAddres
```

That works great, but I can't seem to figure out how I could use it to display the `DNS` and `Subnet mask` as well. I know this is probably a noob question, but they've changed a bit of stuff and I'm trying to find a cut and dry way of doing it without too much code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem you are getting with WMI, it is pretty straight forward?
You can try using wbemtest for better picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could retrieve this information using `WMI`:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
   Where IPEnabled | 
   Select IPSubnet, DNSServerSearchOrder, IpAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

With PWSH 7.x, `WMI` won't be available. So that will of course be:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
  Where IPEnabled |
    Select IPSubnet, DNSServerSearchOrder, IpAddress
```